# Cannot redeclare Laravel's __() function when using oscarotero/gettext translation library

Tags: php, laravel

I have a set of translations in PHP array. Using Oscarotero's gettext library, I'm getting an error of:

> "Cannot redeclare __() (previously declared in
>   D:\LocaleTesting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:907)"
>   when the execution of the code *$t->register()*

```php
 $aTranslation = Translations::fromJsonFile(public_path() . '/locale/'.$sLocale.'/LC_MESSAGES/admin.json');
 $oTranslator = new Translator();
 $oTranslator->loadTranslations($aTranslation);
 $oTranslator->register();
```

Also, I've search that this error only occur when your Laravel version is 5.4 and above. Any help will do. Thank you! Please [Oscarotero/gettext](https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext)'s github for more information about the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a know issue with the library:
https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext/issues/180

One way around it is loading the translator functions before laravel helpers are loaded (solution from the issue above):

> I'm using the package with a require before `vendor/autoload.php` on `public/index.php` and `artisan` command.
>
> ```
> # public/index.php
> require __DIR__.'/../vendor/gettext/gettext/src/translator_functions.php';
> require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
> ```
>
> ```
> # artisan
> require __DIR__.'/vendor/gettext/gettext/src/translator_functions.php';
> require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
> ```

Comment: This works on me. Thanks @atymic!

But how about i create a new function of __() that accepts 2 parameters., like __('param1', 'param2'), how can I make this global php function? Like if I call the __() function in my blade, it executes my created functions and not the gettext's __()? But still, I will use the gettext of oscarotero's gettext. Thank you!